# Reorder menu items without affecting database id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a menu in my Laravel application which lists tags. I want to be able to add more tags and change their order, but I don't want to affect the underlying database ids for each tag. Because that would break any data I have already associated with them. So I thought I add an extra column to my database called 'display_order' like so:

Database:

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('display_order');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
 });
```

Now I want to create a view to let the user change the value of the display_order field. Initially I show a page which prints each tag and its display_order and allows the user to update the value in a text field:

Controller:

```
public function showTagsOrder()
{
    $tags = Tag::all()->sortBy('display_order');
    return view('menu.tags', compact('tags'));
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/menu/tags', ['as' => 'menu_tags', 'uses' => 'MenuOrderController@showTagsOrder']);
```

View:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'MenuOrderController@updateTagsOrder']) !!}
            @foreach($tags->chunk(18) as $chunk)
                <div class="col">
                    @foreach($chunk as $tag)
                        <p><label>{!! $tag->name !!}</label><input type="text" name="tag_array[{!! $tag->id !!}]" value="{!! $tag->display_order !!}" class="numeric" />
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            @endforeach
        <p>{!! Form::submit('Submit') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When the form is submitted I then have the following function in my controller:

```
public function updateTagsOrder(TagsMenuRequest $request)
{

        $i = 1;
        foreach($request->tag_array as $tag_value)
        {
            $tag = new Tag; 
            $tag = Tag::find($i);
            $tag->display_order = $tag_value;
            $tag->save();
            $i++;
        }
        flash()->overlay('The order of tags in the menu has been udpated!', 'Congratulations');
        return redirect('/');
}
```

But this doesn't work. How would I rewrite this so I assigned the correct value for display_order to each tag. I'd be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach($request->tag_array as $tag_id => $tag_value)
    {
        $tag = Tag::find($tag_id);
        $tag->display_order = $tag_value;
        $tag->save();
    }
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help :)